# As System in Sqlplus, how do I query another user's table?

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus, ora-00942

According to  select name from system_privilege_map System has been granted:

```
SELECT ANY TABLE
```

...and lots of other * ANY TABLES.

Plainly running

```
select * from the_table;
select * from the_table;
```

...nets the given response:

> ERROR at line 1:
>   ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

I can log in as that user and run the same command just fine.

I'm running under the assumption I should be able to run queries (select in this case) agaisnt a general user's DB table. Is my assumption correct, and if so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the_table is owned by user "some_user" then:

```
select * from some_user.the_table;
```

Answer (score 9):

As the previous responses have said, you can prefix the object name with the schema name:

```
SELECT * FROM schema_name.the_table;
```

Or you can use a synonym (private or public):

```
CREATE (PUBLIC) SYNONYM the_table FOR schema_name.the_table;
```

Or you can issue an alter session command to set the default schema to the the one you want:

```
ALTER SESSION SET current_schema=schema_name;
```

Note that this just sets the default schema, and is the equivalent of prefixing all (unqualified) object names with `schema_name`.  You can still prefix objects with a different schema name to access an object from another schema.  Using `SET current_schema` does not affect your privileges: you still have the privileges of the user you logged in as, not the schema you have set.

Answer (score 4):

You need to do:

```
SELECT * FROM schema_name.the_table;
```

Or use SYNONYMs...

```
CREATE SYNONYM the_table FOR schema_name.the_table;
```